# Adapter.UpdateCommand not working - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner and I have one problem. I whant to change data in my database and when I passing a parameter to the base, Im using an **adapter.selectCommand** and request are successfully executed. But when I change my code to **adapter.UpdateCommand** I have no data into database, it is not working. Source and databse are: **VB.NET and SQL**

This is my code:

```
    con.Close()

    Dim com As New SqlCommand
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlDS As New Data.DataSet

    con.Open()
    Dim startTrasaction = con.BeginTransaction

    Try

        exe = "basicInsert"

        com = New SqlCommand(exe, con)
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Integer.Parse(txtID.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CStr(txtName.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", CStr(txtLastName.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tel", Integer.Parse(txtTel.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emali", (txtMail.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", CStr(txtStatus.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", CStr(txtState.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", CStr(txtTown.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", CStr(txtAdress.Text))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateID", (txtStateID.Text))



        com.Transaction = startTrasaction

        adp.UpdateCommand = com   ' NOT WORKING



        'adp.SelectCommand = com   ' WORKING FINE


        adp.Fill(sqlDS)


        adp.Dispose()
        com.Dispose()


        startTrasaction.Commit()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        startTrasaction.Rollback()

    Finally

        con.Close()

        txtID.ResetText()
        txtName.ResetText()
        txtLastName.ResetText()
        txtTel.ResetText()
        txtMail.ResetText()
        txtStatus.ResetText()
        txtState.ResetText()
        txtTown.ResetText()
        txtAdress.ResetText()

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common misunderstanding. The `SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand` is called in service only if the DataTable or the DataSet passed to the [`SqlDataAdapter.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx) method contains changed rows.

In your scenario above, you are just loading data in a DataSet and this works fine, but there are no changes in the DataSet and you don't call the `SqlDataAdapter.Update` method.

If you want to insert a new row in the database just call the `ExecuteNonQuery` method of the SqlCommand

Try

```
    exe = "basicInsert"

    com = New SqlCommand(exe, con)
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Integer.Parse(txtID.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CStr(txtName.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", CStr(txtLastName.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tel", Integer.Parse(txtTel.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emali", (txtMail.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", CStr(txtStatus.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", CStr(txtState.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", CStr(txtTown.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", CStr(txtAdress.Text))
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateID", (txtStateID.Text))

    com.ExecuteNonQuery()

    .... the following adapter.SelectCommand should be able to see the new record
```

Comment: Could you show me one example how to use: SqlDataAdapter.Update and SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand Method, I'd appreciate it

Comment: The link above to the MSDN article on the Update method is a good starting point (see the example in the Update(DataSet) where you can find also remarks on the underlying mechanism)